# I got Hibernate exception while I create Query

Tags: java, model-view-controller, controller

When I get all list ob books from database, all is OK. I use method "public List listBooks()" in my DAO class. But when I try to filter books by some parameters throw other method: "public List listBooksFiltered(String title, String author)" , i got exception.

---

There U have part of books.jsp file:

[books.jsp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bb9PV.png)

---

There U have part of @Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "books", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listBooks (Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("book", new Book());
    model.addAttribute("listBooks", this.bookService.listBooks());

    return "books";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/books/filtering", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String listBooksFiltered (@RequestParam("title") String title, @RequestParam("author") String author,  Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("book", new Book());
    model.addAttribute("listBooks", this.bookService.listBooksFiltered(title, author));

    return "books";
}
```

---

There U have part of BookDaoImpl.class:

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Book> listBooks() {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    List<Book> bookList = session.createQuery("from Book").list(); // special query for loading all objects Book.class

    for(Book book: bookList) {
        logger.info("Book list: " + book);
    }
    return bookList;
}

@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Book> listBooksFiltered(String title, String author) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    Query query = session.createQuery("from Book where bookTitle = :paramTitle");
    query.setParameter("paramTitle", title);
    List<Book> bookList = query.list();

    for(Book book: bookList) {
        logger.info("Book list: " + book);
    }
    return bookList;
}
```

Comment: What is the exception you get?

Comment: Message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread

Comment: Root Cause

org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
 org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:106)
 org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014)
 com.springapp.mvc.dao.BookDaoImpl.listBooksFiltered(BookDaoImpl.java:85)

Answer (score 0):

OK I have a solution!  the reason is:

I forgot to type @Transactional annotation in service class method, which  was between controller and Dao-class. So probably Hibernate stopped his calculation on this method.